# CSS working only on localhost, IE11 and compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, ie-compatibility-mode

I am working in ASP Classic in some olds html tables in an old site that just work in Compatibility Mode. The browser is IE11, and I think the compatibility mode is in IE7

The table has two parts: Header and info. So, my boss want to make a fixed header. So I do this in CSS:

```
.scroll-tabla {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
.scroll-tabla thead tr  {
        position: relative;
    }
```

And the table:

```
<div class="scroll-tabla">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>..title 1...</th>
        <th>..title 2...</th>
        <!-- theader contents -->
        <th>..title F...</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <!-- tbody contents -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried in my localhost and it works, the header stay fixed on top of the table even id I scroll down scroll. But just in localhost.

I tried on my remote server with a URL and in my own machine loading the site with my IP in another machine and the header scrolls with the rest of the table.

Also I try this:

```
.scroll-tabla thead tr  {
        position: relative;
        top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop); 
}
```

but doesn't work. I don't have any clues why or how this happens. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check which browser mode you were in both cases ? I guess that when connecting to remote site you switch to compatibility mode or so...

Comment: Have you tried adding a meta tag to render the page in IE 7 no matter what version a user is using of IE? Something similar to: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

Comment: In both  case I am in compatibility mode. However I dicovered that if add the site in trusted mode, works. O.o